# The configuration section 'serviceAutoStartProviders' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire, iis-10

I am working on Hangfire, I want to use "serviceAutoStartProviders" in web.config for auto start. But where should I define "serviceAutoStartProviders" in web.config?

I got an error message of:

> The configuration section 'serviceAutoStartProviders' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

My code is as below in web.configration:

```
<system.web>
    <serviceAutoStartProviders>
        <add name="ApplicationPreload" type="WebApplication1.ApplicationPreload, WebApplication1" />
    </serviceAutoStartProviders>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be defined inside a `system.applicationHost` element. If you take a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/serviceautostartproviders/), you can see this from the doc structure (and even the URL path used) though I admit it's not particularly clear. For example:

```
<system.applicationHost>
    <serviceAutoStartProviders>
        <add name="ApplicationPreload" type="...." />
    </serviceAutoStartProviders>
</system.applicationHost>
```

Comment: Thank you. but  <serviceAutoStartProviders> giving me error in web.config file. underline error.

Comment: The docs say *The <serviceAutoStartProviders> element is configured at the global level in the ApplicationHost.config file.* so you may need to do it in there?